# In python how can I pass the username and password from a variable to cx_Oracle.connect in python

Tags: python, oracle

here is what I want to perform

```
dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn('&hostname,$port,$servicename)
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=&user, password= &password , dsn=dsn_tns)
```

in the above function &value is my variable , I know & does not work in Python , but i want how to pass these variables as parameters

Comment: If you have a variable named `port`, then just use it like that.  Don't put `$` or `&` in front of it.

Comment: I see this has been answered, but just to note: `&var` is SQL\*Plus syntax, not Python syntax.  And `$var` is syntax in a bunch of languages but not Python

Comment: Thanks For your response it worked, I have recently started writing Python , so you may see many such kind questions :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could directly use the variable name and assign it, no need of using `&` and `$`:

```
hostname = host1
port = 1521
servicename = orcl
username = my_user
password = xxxx

dsn_tns = cx_Oracle.makedsn(hostname, port, servicename)
conn = cx_Oracle.connect(user=username, password=password, dsn=dsn_tns)
```

Read more about `cx_Oracle` in [documentation](https://cx-oracle.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user_guide/connection_handling.html).